# Open tar-file that ends with .b

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar file that ends with .b and I don't know how to open it. Neither in windows, neither Linux I've been successful to open it.

```
data.ext4.tar.b
```

Another tar that ends with .a could easily be opened in Windows

```
data.ext4.tar.a
```

What's is the difference? How can I possibly open the .b tar?

*This is from an Android OS image - a nandroid backup. .a consists of all the apps and hopefully .b consists of pictures*

Comment: It might be compressed; if you use the `file` command, it can give more information: `file data.ext4.tar.b`

Comment: @ThomasDickey - this was returned: **data.ext4.tar.b: data**

Comment: Do you also have a data.ext4.tar file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup), that is a compressed tar-file using the *deflate* method.  The accepted answer in that thread points to a program which you might use: [nelenkov/android-backup-extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor)

There also is this, which might work: [Android Backup Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/).

The `deflate` method is one of those which web servers might return, but is less used than `gzip`.  The `file` program may not know about it.

Further reading:

- [Why use deflate instead of gzip for text files served by Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388595/why-use-deflate-instead-of-gzip-for-text-files-served-by-apache)
- [An Explanation of the DEFLATE Algorithm](http://www.gzip.org/deflate.html)
- [Choosing a Compression Method](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_compression.htm) (WinZip)

Comment: thanks but I did the backup with clockworkmod and all tar-files and .img's are wrapped together in a .zip-file

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something split the file. When you try to un-`tar` the `.a` file does it abort early? That's a hint that it is split. Is the `.a` file 4GB? That's another hint. Try concatenating the files on a machine that can handle large files...

```
cp myfile.tar.a myfile_full.tar
cat myfile.tar.b >> myfile_full.tar
tar xvf myfile_full.tar
```

Comment: thanks, i've a dual boot - right now on Windows - later on i'll try this.

Answer (score -1):

> Whats is the difference? How can I possibly open the .b tar?

As far as I can tell, either ClockworkMod or TAR splits the backup into several files.  If you're able to open the `data.ext4.tar.a` file, it might be because it has the TAR file headers at its start while `data.ext4.tar.b` does not.  To get to the data in `data.ext4.tar.b`, you probably have to combine the split archive files into one single archive file.

On Linux, try to combine all of your TAR files using one of the following commands:

```
$ cat data.ext4.tar.a data.ext4.tar.b > data-combined.tar
$ cat data.ext4.tar* > data-combined.tar
```

Then try to open `data-combined.tar` as you would any other TAR file.

Or, if you're doing this on Windows, try one of the following commands:

```
> copy /b data.ext4.tar.a + data.ext4.tar.b data-combined.tar
> copy /b data.ext4.tar* data-combined.tar
```

Then try to open data-combined.tar as normal.

In both cases, here are what the commands do.  The first command will combine `data.ext4.tar.a` and `data.ext4.tar.b` into `data-combined.tar`.  The second command will combine any file in the current directory that begins with `data.ext4.tar` into `data-combined.tar`, so it can be used if you have more than the two files listed.

Comment: thansk will look into this :-)